# viewport meta tag is not working

Tags: android, html, tags

Hello I have the following website which I am trying to set up with the viewport tag to be rendered in mobile phones for example on a full screen, but it seems that the tag is not working, any suggestions how I can resolve this problem ?

this is the code for the viewport which I am using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

the website is this one: www.heatherlacombe.com

Right now the website is rendering on ipad or android devices like on the half of it I would like to make it to fit the whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

...is correct. However, without a responsive design to your website, it is very limited in its usefulness. I did test the website on my iPad and it display completely although much larger than the screen size itself.

It looks like you are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which makes me wonder why your website is not responsive. I would suggest looking into why your site is not acting responsively before you try and tackle a Viewport issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your site isn't responsive. So you don't really need to have that meta tag in there. If you take the tag out and then look at it on your iPad the site will automatically shrink itself down.